# Mongoose middleware remove - not able to use find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having an issue with mongoose.
I've 2 objects, Section and Products, and my Sections contains references to products.

So, when I delete a product, I want to delete the reference to this product in my section.
For this, in my product model, I use schema.post('remove', ....)
But when using Section.find() inside, I get an error.

Anyone have an idea ?
Here is my code :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Section = require('./section');

var schema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    picture: {type: String},
    description_preview: {type: String},
    description_detail: {type: String},
    benefits_detail: {type: String},
    position: {type: Number},
    sections: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Section'}]
});



schema.post('remove', function (product) {
    product.sections.map ( sectionID => {
        console.log('sectionID dans remove :');
        console.log(sectionID);
        Section.findById(sectionID,  function (err, section) {
            console.log('found')
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occurred',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            if (!section) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'No Message Found!',
                    error: {message: 'Message not found'}
                });
            }
        })
    })
});
```

everything is working till the Section.findById()

Thank you

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please add those details to your post.

Comment: It's an error throwed, catched by my product.delete('/', ...)

Comment: What does the error message read? If you do not see one, wrap the code in `try-catch`, that should show the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Try findOne instaed of findById like

```
   Section.findOne({"_id": sectionID},function (err, section) {
            console.log('found')
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occurred',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            if (!section) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'No Message Found!',
                    error: {message: 'Message not found'}
                });
            }
        })
```

Comment: Yep, I also tried this and this is the same problem. Anyway, it's a little bit less "clean", but I moved the logic directly in my routes, after the delete instruction